# Проблема с асинхронным получение JSON-данных

Tags: android, ajax, json, jquery-mobile

Получаю данные из локального JSON файла методом `$.getJSON`  и вывожу их с помощью jQuery mobile:

```
  $('body').off('tap').on('tap', 'ul li', function(event) {


 var jqxhr = $.getJSON( "one.json", function(data) {
  console.log( "success" );
  alert(data.name+" "+data.one);
  $("#json").html(data.name+" "+data.one);
})
  .done(function() {
    console.log( "second success" );
    $("#d1").html( "second success" );
  })
  .fail(function(jqxhr, textStatus, error) {
       var err = textStatus + ', ' + error;
console.log( "Request Failed: " + err);
$("#d2").html( "Request Failed: " + err);

  })
  .always(function() {
    console.log( "complete" );
    $("#d3").html( "complete" );
  });

});
```

Все вроде бы работает, но не на samsung. На ПК и htc проблем нет. В чем может быть загвоздка, в какую сторону копать?

Comment: в сторону версий Android копать, и соответствующих изменений в `WebView`

Comment: @metalurgus, хоть примерно в чем может быть проблема?